# Delimiter with a condition

Tags: sql

I have a column (MarketID) in a table.
I have to derive a value out of it.
I have to check for occurrence of delimiter(.) in the second position and  see if there are consecutive three numbers  after the delimiter then get that value. If not check for occurrence of delimiter(.) in the fourth position and see if there are consecutive three numbers after the delimiter then get that value
else get 0.

1) In first record: '3.001.1.16', at the second position there is a delimiter(.) and  consecutive 3 number exists (001), so my output would be 001.
.
2)In the second record '3.1.006.4.7',there is a delimiter at second position but we don't have three consecutive numbers so we check for the 4th position and there is a delimiter and consecutive three numbers exist  so the output is 006 .
.
3) no (.) delimiter so output=0.

```
create table dbo.SampleList
(
MarketID varchar(100)
)

insert into dbo.SampleList

select '3.001.1.16'
union all
select '3.1.006.4.7'
union all
select 'D16B000000:21109:4'

select * from dbo.SampleList
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Regular expressions are an obvious way to solve this, but not all databases support them.

Comment: String functions are different for different dbms.  Which dbms are you using?  Tag properly!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming SQL Server from `dbo`, you could use a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT MarketID, 
       CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(MarketID,2,1) = '.' AND TRY_CONVERT(int,SUBSTRING(MarketID,3,3)) IS NOT NULL THEN SUBSTRING(MarketID,3,3)
            WHEN SUBSTRING(MarketID,4,1) = '.' AND TRY_CONVERT(int,SUBSTRING(MarketID,5,3)) IS NOT NULL THEN SUBSTRING(MarketID,5,3)
            ELSE '0'
       END
FROM #SampleList
```

`TRY_CONVERT` to `int` will verify that the 3 characters are numbers

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using a function I've created a few years ago.

It allows you to split a string and get a table as a result.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[splitStringToTable]
(
    @List VARCHAR(MAX) ,
    @Separator VARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS @Results TABLE
(
    ID INT
)
AS      
    BEGIN
        SET @List = @List + ','

        DECLARE @POS INT
        DECLARE @TEMP VARCHAR(8000)

        WHILE (Charindex(@Separator, @List)>0)
        BEGIN
            SET @POS = Charindex(@Separator, @List)
            IF @POS > = 0
            BEGIN
                SET @TEMP = LEFT(@List, @POS-1)
                IF @TEMP <> ''
                    INSERT INTO @Results (ID) VALUES (@TEMP)
                SET @List = Substring(@List, Charindex(@Separator, @List)+len(@Separator), len(@List))
            END
        END
        RETURN
    END
GO
```

Usage:

```
SELECT *, ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM dbo.[splitStringToStringTable](MarketID, '.') WHERE LEN(ID) = 3), 0) AS Result
    FROM SampleList
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MarketID,
(CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(MarketID,2,1) = '.' 
      THEN 
        (CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(MarketID,6,1) = '.' THEN SUBSTRING (MarketID,3,3) 
              WHEN SUBSTRING(MarketID,4,1) = '.' THEN 
                                                (CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(MarketID ,8,1)='.' THEN SUBSTRING(MarketID,5,3) ELSE NULL END)ELSE NULL END)

        WHEN MarketID NOT LIKE '%.%' THEN '0'
        ELSE '0'
        END ) AS Output
FROM dbo.SampleList
```